# What form of encoding do you type into System.out.println in Java?

Tags: java, encoding

I am trying to learn encoding, so please bear with me.

Using an online encoding tool such as [this one](http://www.asciitohex.com/), I can see that the data

```
a
b
```

can be represented

in Ascii/ANSI as:

```
a
b
```

in Hex as:

```
610d0a62
```

in base64 as:

```
YQ0KYg==
```

But in Java if I need to print this data to the screen I need to use the command

```
System.out.println("a\r\nb");
```

What form of encoding is \r\n?

In other words, is it fair to say that \r\n is the keyboard representation for the ascii

```
a
b
```

Comment: Are you asking about what type of encoding escape sequences are?  Or are you trying to encode those escape sequences into something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a real encoding, is an escape character + a character.

It is used to define common ASCII characters which are not printable. The list available to Java is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

Basically `\r` is interpreted as the value 0x0D or 13 in decimal, which is the carriage return.

Comment: Is it fair to say that \r is the keyboard representation of \u0x0D

Comment: It's just a norm chosen many years ago when they required to give a textual representation to ASCII values that didn't have one.